# Newsletter subscription email

Tags: newsletter, magento-1.9.1.1

I am facing below issue in default Magento 1.9.1.1 setup.
I have set `Need to Confirm` under `System->Configuration->Newsletter->Subscription Option` option to `Yes`. 
Now when I am trying to subscribe newsletter via newsletter subscription box in footer, Magento is sending newsletter subscription confirmation email. 
But when I am trying to subscribe newsletter subscription at the create account page while creating account, magento system is not sending any newsletter subscription confirmation email and directly setting the status as `subscribed`.

Comment: yes, its a default functionality. You have to set the email conformation for account creation too.

Comment: Thanks @MeenakshiSundaramR , I never realizes that it is default functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is a default functionality of Magento.

You can check here [Mage_Customer_AccountController::_getCustomer()](https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php#L358-L360)

You can enable the **email conformation for creation creation**.

Or else have to override the `customerAccount controller` to send an email conformation for the newsletter.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behaviour of Magento. Because when you made confirmation of newsletter ON, then Magento will send confirmation E-mail to the given E-mail address in order to confirm whether the given email-address is valid or not.

But for a authenticated user, CONFIRMATION is not necessary. Because he is valid user itself. Hence it is logical that, there is no need for confirmation of email address for a valid user. Hence Magento will send a success mail to authenticated user.

If you want to change this flow, then you should make a module and change the logic flow. ***[Please have a look on this extension](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Advanced-Newsletter)***. It is a good place to start with.